# yank all lines and paste at the end Vim

Tags: vim

Such as title, I want to copy all lines and paste at the end.

BEFORE:

```
apple
cat
dog
sun
```

AFTER:

```
apple apple
cat cat
dog dog
sun sun
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a clever visual-mode solution to this, but I can't figure it out off the top of my head right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a substitue command

```
:%s/.*/& &
```

Where `.*` matches everything and `&` is replaced with the match (in this case the whole line)

---

Or if you really want to yank the lines you could use a normal command

```
:%norm yyPJ
```

Which is run the command `yyPJ` on every line in normal mode.

---

Note: These commands will give slightly different output if there is leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on unix-like system:

```
:%!paste -d' ' % -
```

Answer (score 0):

Another unix-style answer (though I would go with any of @FDinoff's solution):

```
:%!awk '{print $1, $1}'
```

And another `:normal` answer because there's so many ways to enjoy skinning a cat:

```
:%norm y$A <C-v><C-r>"
```

And another one:

```
:%norm y$Pa<space>   <-- just press the <space> bar
```

Comment: Unfortunately `y$` will fail on empty lines, and the subsequent paste will paste the previous non-empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way , if your text is like this(~ represents blank)

```
apple
cat~~
dog~~
sun~~
```

It means that all word has the same numbers of colomn.

you can `ctrl-v` to select all and move cursor to the end  of "apple" and type `p` to paste.